# How to change the upload directory in php?

Tags: php

I have uploaded a Image Data from iPhone app.

I decoded the image Data and tried to save the image in the file.

I'm always receiving an error message as

> file
>   href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in.

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mc311');
$data = base64_decode($Image);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
$path = $file;
```

Comment: You are missing a `/` at the end of `UPLOAD_DIR`

Comment: @Brewal, will that lead to Permission Denied error ? O.o I don't think so.

Comment: Yes it will, see my answer for details.

Comment: Does any of those answers solved the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After try this added `/` after `mc311` and added chmod to upload files:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mc311/');
chmod(UPLOAD_DIR, 777); 
$data = base64_decode($Image);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
$path = $file;
```

Comment: Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mc311/5215dd480fcf9.png) [<a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in  ..........................again im getting this error

Comment: @Bing Where does your `mc311` directory comes from ?

Comment: how to change the upload directory

Comment: @Bing, make use of chdir(UPLOAD_DIR)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran can explain how to change the directory

Comment: @Brewal Sorry.Can u help how to save in this folder

Comment: @Bing start by editing your question with the code you are actually using, with the `mc311` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The "permission denied" message should give you a clue! Check that the defined UPLOAD_DIR is writeable by the web server. Generally chown to www-data:www-data or your webserver username should be OK, but you may have to tweak the permissions too. Start liberally with a chmod 777 and then see if that fixes the issue. Once you have tracked down the problem, you should then secure the directory with more conservative permissions.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a `/` at the end of `UPLOAD_DIR`. Try to `var_dump` your variables. `$file` would give you in this case something like : `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mc3114b3403665fea6.png`.
You are then trying to upload to the `htdocs` directory, which you don't have permission to write in.

Just change this line :

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mc311');
```

by :

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mc311/');
```

Also make sure the `mc311` directory have the good permissions. `755` will be enough :

```
chmod(UPLOAD_DIR, 755);
```

Eventually, if this did not work, if you are under OSX, try this in a terminal :

```
chmod -R 0775 XAMPP/
```

from the `Applications` directory